# subsonic via tomcat on ubuntu move it to top directory, that is root of subdomain

Tags: subsonic

I want to run subsonic on my home server via domain... I configured virtualhost, but I'm trying hard to get rid of subfolder and move it up to subdomain root, but no luck!

Problem with my approach is that I need to go to subdomain.domain.com/streamer to access subsonic.

I tried messing with config options in subsonic.options and removing streamer and leaving variable or / or empty but it didn't help.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName sub.domain.ge
   ServerAlias www.sub.domain.ge
   Redirect permanent / https://sub.domain.ge/

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerAdmin 
  ServerName sub.domain.ge
  ServerAlias www.sub.domain.ge

   DocumentRoot /var/www/

      SSLEngine On
      SSLCertificateFile    /etc/secure/ssl/box_1_a.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/secure/ssl/box_1_a.key

  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
     ProxyRequests Off
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:4040/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4040/
  </IfModule>

   <Directory />
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you tried `DocumentRoot /var/www/streamer` in the virtual host on port 443?

Comment: @AaronMiller yep, I've tried, but this is not virtualhost problem, I think it is subsonic issue...

Comment: Can't help you there; I don't know from subsonic. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to edit subsonic config file which surprisingly wasn't /etc/subsonic/subsonic.properties on my ubuntu server. It was /etc/default/subsonic and variable is called path= . Just removed subsonic from there and left /